# Is it possible to have databinding for action menu with searchView?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-optionsmenu

I have a SearchFragment
and here is my code of onCreateOptionMenu in SearchFragment

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
  }


 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
    val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    val searchManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as? SearchManager

    searchView = searchItem?.actionView as? SearchView
    searchView?.setSearchableInfo(searchManager?.getSearchableInfo(activity?.componentName))


    queryTextListener = object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
      override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {

        return true
      }

      override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {

        viewModel.loadSearchResults(query)
        return true
      }
    }
    searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
  }
```

I would like to know is it possible to have databinding for SearchView of menu  so in the case I wouldn't like to have `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` in Fragment and I can connect viewModel with menu and listen searchView changes in ViewModel 
`android:text="@={viewModel.query}"`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to move your listener to the viewModel directly?

```
class ViewModel: ViewModel() {

   interface ViewModelListener {
       fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String)
       fun onQueryTextSubmit(newQuery: String)
   }

   var listener: ViewModelListener? = null
   var query = ObservableField<String>()

   val queryTextListener = object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
       override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
          listener?.onQueryTextChange(newText: String)
          return true
       }

       override fun onQueryTextSubmit(newQuery: String): Boolean {
           listener?.onQueryTextSubmit(newQuery: String)
           query.set(newQuery)
           return true
       }
   }
}
```

And assign it in your onViewCreated like `searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(viewModel.queryTextListener)`

Also you can add listener `viewModel.listener = this`